# How to make a validation on a calculated field in laravel 5.5

Tags: forms, laravel, validation, input, custom-validators

I want to know how to validate the calculated value of a input field .

For example I have a field named `birthDate` I want to accept the date only if the calculated age from `birthDate` is less than 16 .

I want to make the validation within a custom `Request` class

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Validator::extend('youngerThan', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $maxAge = ( ! empty($parameters)) ? (int) $parameters[0] : 16;

    //return (new DateTime)->diff(new DateTime($value))->y <= $minAge;



    // or the same using Carbon

    $dob = new Carbon\Carbon($value);

    return $dob->age >= $minAge;
});
```

This way you can use the rule for any age you like:

```
$rules = ['dob' => 'youngerThan']; 
$rules = ['dob' => 'youngerThan:15'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution by creating a class `Rule` this is available in `Laravel 5.5`

The solution I'll propose is for Older than an age

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class OlderThan implements Rule
{

    protected $minAge=16;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value,$parameters)
    {
        if( empty($parameters) )
        {

            $minAge = $parameters[0];

        }

        return $this->getAge($value) >= $minAge;

    }


    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {

        return 'L\'age doit être supérieur à'.$minAge;

    }



    private function getAge($value)
    {
        $dob = new Carbon\Carbon($value);

        return $dob->age  ;
    }
}
```